# Treeview changes color of Item Image

Tags: c, winapi

So I've been trying to add images to my WinAPI TreeView Common Control items. However, I have encountered something that has really been bothering me and I have no clue why it is happening. For some reason, the Image in a TreeView has a different color than the actual bitmap does. I took a screenshot of a test program I made that paints a BMP image file along with its TreeView counterpart. (It is the **exact** same image yet both drawings yield different results).

[image: Window Screenshot]

As you can see the image on the left is what it should look like and the image on the right is what the TreeView is drawing. Is this just the way TreeView works or something? Or is there something in my code that I'm doing wrong? It would be much appreciated if anyone could point this out because out of personal taste, the TreeView image looks visually disgusting and I would like the TreeView Control to draw my image correctly :P

The following is the code I am using to create the Treeview:

```
    //Load image from relative file path
    g_hBmp = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

    //Create Treeview
    HWND treeview = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, NULL,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | TVS_FULLROWSELECT,
        250, 100, 500, 300,
    hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    //Add single treeview item
    TVITEM tvi = {0};
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins = {0};

    HIMAGELIST himl = NULL;
    himl = ImageList_Create(90, 90, 0, 1, 0);
    int image = ImageList_Add(himl, g_hBmp, NULL);

    SendMessage(treeview, TVM_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM) TVSIL_NORMAL, (LPARAM) himl);

    tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE;

    //Set Text
    tvi.pszText = "Some Item";
    tvi.cchTextMax = sizeof("Some Item") - 1;
    tvi.iImage = image;

    tvins.item = tvi;
    tvins.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
    SendMessage(treeview, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT) &tvins);
```

And here is my **entire** code in case you want to copy it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

HBITMAP g_hBmp = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {

        case WM_CREATE: {

            //Load Image
            g_hBmp = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

            //Create Treeview
            HWND treeview = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, NULL,
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | TVS_FULLROWSELECT,
                250, 100, 500, 300,
            hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            //Add single treeview item
            TVITEM tvi = {0};
            TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins = {0};

            HIMAGELIST himl = NULL;
            himl = ImageList_Create(90, 90, 0, 1, 0);
            int image = ImageList_Add(himl, g_hBmp, NULL);

            SendMessage(treeview, TVM_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM) TVSIL_NORMAL, (LPARAM) himl);

            tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE;

            //Set Text
            tvi.pszText = "Some Item";
            tvi.cchTextMax = sizeof("Some Item") - 1;
            tvi.iImage = image;

            tvins.item = tvi;
            tvins.hInsertAfter = TVI_FIRST;
            SendMessage(treeview, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT) &tvins);

            break;

        }
        case WM_PAINT: {

            PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};

            //Setup
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HDC hdcPaint = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

            HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcPaint, g_hBmp);

            //Painting
            BitBlt(hdc, 100, 100, 90, 90, hdcPaint, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            //Cleanup
            SelectObject(hdcPaint, hBmpOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcPaint);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;

        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {

            DeleteObject(g_hBmp);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        }
        default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return 0;

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

    InitCommonControls();

    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Parent Window";
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, "Render Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1000, 1000 / 16 * 9,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }

    return msg.wParam;

}
```

Comment: Make sure to specify the correct bit depht in the call to `ImageList_Create()`: [Image List Creation Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/ilc-constants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above by 'Swordfish', what I was missing was the proper flag when calling the `ImageList_Create()` function. As you can see in my call to `ImageList_Create(90, 90, 0, 1, 0);` I specify '0' as the third parameter (which represents the [Image List Creation Flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/ilc-constants)). As stated in the documentation, the *ILC_COLOR* flag has a value of zero; when this flag is set it uses the 'default behavior' which is often *ILC_COLOR4* (i.e. 4 bits per channel).

To fix this all I needed to do was simply call the function using the *ILC_COLOR24* flag, indicating that my images have a 24-bit depth.

```
ImageList_Create(90, 90, ILC_COLOR24, 1, 0);
```